# How to fix: Django error: no such table: main.classroom_student__old

Tags: python, django

I am following [this tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html) for learning how to create a Django (v2.0.1) app with multiple user types (teachers and students in this case). I cloned the associated code from the [Github Repository](https://github.com/sibtc/django-multiple-user-types-example), migrated the pre-made migrations and ran the site on localhost using:

```
python3 manage.py migrate
python3 manage.py runserver
```

The site works almost perfectly (Teacher sign up, login, quiz creation, and student log in are all in order). However, the student Signup fails with the following error:

```
OperationalError at /accounts/signup/student/
no such table: main.classroom_student__old
```

With the traceback pointing eventually to the file

```
django_school/classroom/forms.py, line 39:
student.interests.add(*self.cleaned_data.get('interests'))
```

That line comes from the definition of the following class in that forms.py file:

```
class StudentSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    interests = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Subject.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        required=True
    )

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_student = True
        user.save()
        student = Student.objects.create(user=user)
        student.interests.add(*self.cleaned_data.get('interests'))
        return user
```

**What I have tried:**
Following answers to the many similar questions on this site, I assumed it was a migration issue so I tried running:

```
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb

Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: crispy_forms, humanize, messages, staticfiles
  Apply all migrations: auth, classroom, contenttypes, sessions
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

But the error persisted. I then deleted `db.sqlite3` as well as all migration files associated with the app classroom. I then ran `python3 manage.py makemigrations` followed by `python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb`, again to no avail.

This makes me think that this is an issue with the way the code is adding "interests" to the "student" user object. Indeed, commenting out the line in question stops the error and creates the new student user, however this has the obvious issue that the student has no interests stored.

Running `python manage.py sqlmigrate classroom 0001` shows:

```
...
-- Add field quizzes to student
--
ALTER TABLE "classroom_student" RENAME TO "classroom_student__old";
CREATE TABLE "classroom_student" ("user_id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY       KEY REFERENCES "classroom_user" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED);
INSERT INTO "classroom_student" ("user_id") SELECT "user_id" FROM     "classroom_student__old";
DROP TABLE "classroom_student__old";
COMMIT;
```

So the database in question (classroom_student__old) is getting created and deleted when another attribute "quizzes" is added to the student user object. Could this be creating the issue?

Comment: I clone the repository and tried and student signup worked well. Try delete whole dir and try again

Comment: Thank you for the quick response seuling. That is so interesting that it works for you. I deleted everything, opened a new terminal, started a fresh virtual environment, and tried again but have the exact same issue.

Comment: It's so weird because I couldn't find any table like `classroom_student__old`. Also it will work same at same env. Could you tell your env and python version?

Comment: If you are using sqlite for the project then check the version of the sqlite being used. There's a reported bug which breaks the foreign key relationship after upgrade. 
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29182

In case if you have pulled the db.sqlite file also you can remove the file, delete everythin in migrations folder apart from __init__.py and can start over.

Comment: @SwapnilBhate indeed it was the sqlite version 3.26.0! after downgrading to 3.24.0, deleting the directory, and reinstalling, everything works perfectly. I never would have thought of that, thank you very much for your help everyone! How should I proceed to close the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close the question, @SwapnilBhate had the correct answer; it was the sqlite version 3.26.0. After downgrading to 3.24.0, deleting the directory, and reinstalling, everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of downgrading to sqlite 3.24.0, another solution for making the tutorial you listed run successfully is to change the requirements.txt file's django version to 2.2.7 before running the "pip install -r requirements.txt" command.

So, your requirements.txt file for this project would be:

Django==2.2.7

django-crispy-forms==1.7.0

pytz==2017.3

Comment: Solved it for me. Thank you! :-D

Answer (score -1):

1.0) First try:

```
python manage.py migrate YOURAPPNAME --fake
```

2.0) If it still doesn't working delete all the migrations **files** inside your app migrations(*except **init**.py*) and *pycache* folder. After that run makemigrations and migrate.

Comment: Hi Lorran, thank you for your reply. I tried both of these steps and I still get the same error **only** when trying to sign up as a student `django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: main.classroom_student__old`. The fact that it worked smoothly for seuling makes me wonder if it is something about my system. Is that possible? I am running on the terminal of a MacBook Pro OS High Sierra.

Comment: I took a look at your models and coudnt really find this table... May youre referencing it "mistakely" somewhere ? Also, can you post the full django's traceback ?

Answer (score -1):

Use django==2.2.7
then `python manage.py migrate`,
and finally `python runserver`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for the answer.  However, your answer could be better if you explained why are you locking the Django version, since that is a decision that is quite critical for some users for security concerns. If there's a bug in newer versions leading to the error of the asker, that should be explained, supported by credible sources if required. Please edit your answer include more insights on this.